# java8 war deployment fails in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, java-8, activemq-classic

I have migrated my spring app from java 7 to java 8 and done relevant changes in pom.xml. I am getting error when I deploying the war into tomcat server during startup. But it works well in java 7. Please see the below exception and share your suggestions.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'optimusMQ' defined in file [D:\Projects\ESS\optimus_java8_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\optimus\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\web-applicationContext-jms.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/transaction/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/transaction/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:392)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:908)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: i can see `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/transaction/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry; ` do you have JTA jar in classpath?

Comment: I have added JTA in common dependencyManagement pom.xml. But its not present under war's lib folder.

Comment: I am not sure why its not part of your war. Your dependency should be like this. `<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
 <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
 <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
` if still facing same issue place the JTA jar in tomcat lib directory, it should work.

Comment: Yes I have manually placed the jta jar under the war but its still causing issue. And how it could be deployed in JAVA 7 with JTA issue.

Comment: In STS, in few spring configs its showing Error occured processing XML 'com/essvote/optimus/data/admin/jpa/repository/BolKeysRepository : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0'. See Error Log for 
 more details

Comment: You may have to check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error]